# Django deployed project file writing permissions and path

Tags: python, django, apache

As mentioned under the `Where should this code live ?` heading on the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) I have created a Django project at the location `/home/user/Documents/project` such that the directory structure is as mentioned below:

```
project/
    manage.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    app/
       __init__.py
       views.py

    other/
```

In `views.index` I have a open call which opens file under the `other` folder and writes some data on it and then processes it further. The open call is based on relative path as `open('other/file','w')` because by default the Django development server runs from the `project/` directory and starts looking for relative paths from there.

Now, once I deployed it on `apache2` using `mod_wsgi` I can see in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file that the `open` call fails, because it is unable to find the filepath. Please guide me as to how can I resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: could you share your Wsgi config you wrote in the `apache2.conf` file

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI https://codeshare.io/nCStF

Comment: try using base_dir from your settings module: `from settings import BASE_DIR`, now you can `open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'other/file'))`

Comment: @Ali that gives me a permission denied error `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/Documents/project/other/file'`, probably because the server doesn't have permission to write there, right ?

Comment: exactly, now set the appropriate permissions and you're good to go.